# Rigid Body on falling Clock animation

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I can't find any reference for creating this:

[image: falling clock with chain]

It works quite hard using chain & Rigid Body and it's done, but the rotated clock needle during clock is falling it's always failure.

I've used *Connect/Rigid Body Constraint* for a clock with the needle, but it doesn't stay as the normal. Should we always attach whatever the falling clock object & the needle also rotating clockwise?

[image]

Comment: tbh I didn't get much of your question... it seems you have a falling clock as rigid body, and some troubles on movement of the clock's needle...?

Comment: yes .. the clock needle should be attach but it cannot